# Are there any statistics on reliability and failure rate of Service Fabric remoting?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm architecting a system in service fabric and have an edge case where two actors make calls back and forth between each other could become deadlocked if the remoting call fails and invokes a method more than once.

Multiple invocations is not an issue but the potential delay waiting for the deadlocked calls to time out will be a problem if it occurs often.

I just want to understand how frequently remoting fails and if I need to change my design to deal with it.

Regards,
Eli

Comment: Did you consider an event driven approach as an alternative? So fire & forget messaging between Actors. This would avoid your issue and make a more flexible solution.

Comment: As far as I know there is no fire & forget option for actors when the communication must be reliable. The event system is "best effort" delivery which wont work here.

Comment: It's not too hard to create that. Here's an example:https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors